# How to flip image on click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image which flips on hover. This is my code below. The code is taken from w3schools.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">

      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

- Please run the code snippet and view it in full screen.
- When pasting the code here, somehow on hover the image flips but
  comes back to its original state in few seconds. This code however
  runs fine in w3schools. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card

As you can see, the image flips fine on hover. But I need to flip the image only if I click on it.

Now I looked up the css where the flip happens. This is what I found

```
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Now I looked up some solutions online and made the following changes.

The css for flip is changed where I add a class hover

```
 .flip-card.hover .flip-card-inner {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
```

In the javascript (or jquery in this case) this is how I ensure the flip

```
$('.flip-card').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

But when then the flip doesn't happen on click. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: then don't use "hover" in your css

Comment: you are trying to transform from 180 degrees (from the hover) to 180 degrees of the flip, which results in a rotateY of 0 degrees. Try to differentiate the 2 or remove :hover case for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine when the click function can be called.

Just add

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  $('.flip-card').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
  });

});
```

In this case this is when the DOM is loaded.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/f5yn063s/

FYI: also don't forget to change the :hover to .hover

Answer (score 0):

Add a `class` for ex `.fliped` to your css instead of `.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner` and remove `hover` and use `toggleClass()` to add/remove this class to your element, and `find()`. Don't forget, you need to use `rotateY` `.fliped` class  on `.flip-card-inner` not `.flip-card`

```js
$('.flip-card').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.flip-card-inner').toggleClass('fliped')
});
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner,*/
.fliped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)!important;
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">

      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Also if you want to add class to `.fliped`, you can try below example:

```js
$('.flip-card').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover')
});
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/*.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)!important;
}*/

.flip-card.hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)!important;
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">

      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's already here *!* , just click on `Show code snippet` link *!* @SouvikRay

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use the javascript part in `ready` method.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flip-card').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
  })
});
```

It works.
Check on js fiddle please:
https://jsfiddle.net/4yt7Lozc/2/